# Adding a second chainring to a 1X

Tags: chainring, gravel, modification, 1x11

I have a 1X gravel bike with an 11-46 cassette and a 40T chainring. This gearing works for most of my riding but there are times when I'm doing some serious climbing that it would great to have one or two lower gears. I know that converting this to a 2X would a very expensive proposition and may not even be possible on my bike so I wondered if it would be possible to just add a 30T chain ring and manually move the chain on to it in those rare instances when I need lower gears. I found a compatible chain ring and installed it and it seems to work except for the fact that my derailleur can't handle the range. So my question is, is there a derailleur or cage extender that would make this possible and are there other factors I need to consider...or this is even possible?

Specifications:
Crank FSA Omega Megaexo 40T
Cassette: Sunrace 11-46 CSMS8
Derailleur: Sram Apex1 11 speed
Shifter – Sram Apex 11 speed Double-Tap

Comment: e*thirteen does a 12-speed 556% 9-50t. As 30/40 + 11-46 gives 557% gear range, it might be a better  option to consider a larger cassette range. (good range listed here https://bikepacking.com/index/wide-range-cassettes/)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful but don't think I can swap an 11 speed cassette for 12 speed??? And I think my derailleur is at it's current limit.

Comment: Plenty of 11 speeds - Sunrace do an 11-51 which is a huge range. Do you really push 40-11 often enough that you could not drop to a 36 or 38 chain ring. Your going to need to replace the derailleur anyway as it does not have the capacity for 30/40 and 11/46.

Comment: A smaller chainring is a good idea but 40T is the smallest my crank will accommodate apparently. I think the 11-51 cassette is the best option but now I need to know if my derailleur can handle it.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, after a considerable amount of research and frustration I have found the answer: replace my FSA crankset with a SRAM Rival 1 and 36T chainring. This will give me an additional two lower gears with the same 11-46 derailleur. My current FSA crank can't take anything smaller than a 40T. I will lose a bit at the top end but that's a small sacrifice for being able ride up steep hills in relative comfort. This isn't cheap because it requires a new crank with a 42T ring I don't want!!!!, a new 36T that I do want, a new BB because FSA and SRAM aren't compatible!!! So about $CDN 450 installed. Luckily the installation is pretty straightforward. Could do it myself but would rather pay the $50 in case there are any issues.
I wish the bike store had suggested this option when I bought the bike a year ago!!!

Comment: Great solution - thank you for coming back and sharing to provide closure.

Answer (score 3):

While it sounds like a feasable proposition in theory, you will find that the SRAM 1x derailleurs need the chaingap to be quite specifically set up to shift through the gears properly on the wide range cassette. In practice this means that you would have to adjust the b-screw to set the derailleur's chain gap properly every time you switched rings.

This leaves aside the problem of chainline and chainring alignment, which can be fudged to a certain extent in traditional systems but would need special attention here if the chainring aligns to the middle of the "double" position (and has thick/thin teeth!).

Comment: Thanks, yes, I wondered about chainline and b screw settings.

Comment: Need an 11 speed derailleur with a 45 tooth capacity and 46 tooth max sproket size.

Comment: To add insult to injury, if you could somehow add a second chainring, you’d still need a new big ring, because 1x rings have narrow-wide teeth that really aren’t conducive to shifting.